# How can I fold GNU C style functions in Vim correctly?

Tags: vim, folding

When writing C code, I use a mixture of [GNU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#GNU_style) and [K&R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R_style) style. This means that the return value, each parameter and the opening body curly brace of a function is on its own line. I would also like to use Vim's folding feature but with `foldmethod=syntax`, the folding looks like this:

[image: bad-folding]

Is it possible to see the function name in the fold summary without any special fold markers or `foldexpr`s?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762310/how-can-i-automatically-fold-a-long-c-code-in-vim

Comment: @matthias find you some solution for the correct folding in C?

Comment: No unfortunately not. And because of that I do not fold C code except manually :-(

Answer (score 2):

Something which might be a good compromise - if you use the `indent` fold - is to set the `foldminlines` parameter to a higher number.

```
:set foldmethod=indent
:set foldminlines=5
```

If most of your functions are long, it will affect only your list of parameters. The downside obviously is, that it will automatically unfold also small functions which are smaller then 5 lines long.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as a starting point (I have it in my vimrc but I found it online):

```
" Folding {
function! CssFoldText()
    let line = getline(v:foldstart)
    let nnum = nextnonblank(v:foldstart + 1)
    while nnum < v:foldend+1
        let line = line . " " . substitute(getline(nnum), "^ *", "", "g")
        let nnum = nnum + 1 
    endwhile
    return line
endfunction

setlocal foldtext=CssFoldText()
setlocal foldmethod=marker
setlocal foldmarker={,}
setlocal fillchars=fold:/
setlocal foldlevel=-1
"   highlight Folded term=underline cterm=bold gui=bold guifg=Blue guibg=Black
"   highlight FoldColumn term=underline cterm=bold gui=bold guifg=Blue guibg=Black
"}
```